# "Add New Constraints" disabled for UIView in Prototype Cell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Using Storyboards ... Inside of a prototype cell, I added a UIView. I noticed that the UIView does not resize when run on a larger device. I thought that I would try to fix that by adding constraints. Unfortunately, when I click on "Add New Constraints", I can't add any b/c they are disabled. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Share a screenshot showing the selected view and its disabled constraints. You may be selecting `contentView` instead of the`view`you placed in the cell.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add constraints within a Subtitle style cell. Select the cell prototype and set its style to Custom:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**My experience...**

I ran into this problem when I wanted to place tableView on new ViewController.
In "Size Inspector" section you need to change Layout by installing "Automatic".
After that, the menu "Add New Constraint "became available.

[image]